# I'm creating an NPM Package. How do install 'peerDependency' when a user installs my NPM package?

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, npm-publish

I'm having an issue with [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons). I have it install as a `dependency` and `peerDependency`, but when I install my NPM Package into a project, I'm getting an error. To my understanding, a peerDependency is a dependency used for npm packages so packages of my NPM library are installed. Is that correct?

In my NPM library, I have manually linked [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) in my podfile and info.plist:

**podfile**

```
pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
```

**info.plist**

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
  <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
  <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
  <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>Feather.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
  <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
  <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
  <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
  <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
</array>
```

**package.json**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.60.25",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.5",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.12.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "*",
    "react-native": "*",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0"
  },
```

Comment: which version of Rn are you using?

Comment: I'm on version 0.61.5

Comment: You're using ```react-native``` version ```0.61.5```, which means that you don't need to manually link ```react-native-vector-icons```, cause this new version of react-native came with an autolinking feature. By the way, what's the error that you're getting?

Comment: Error: undefined Unable to resolve module 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons' from 'node_modules/react-native-contact-action-sheet/dist/ContactActionSheet.js': react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons could not be found within the project

Comment: ^ That's the error when I try to automatically link react-native-vector-icons. I install my library react-native-contact-action-sheet to a fresh project, and that's the error. Not sure how to do this, but I need react-native-vector-icons to be installed when my NPM Package is installed